Where in OT do we find the narrative of Zechariah, son of Barachias whom Jesus is referring to in Mtt 23:35?
We see Jesus lamenting over the hypocrisy and stubbornness of the Scribes and Pharisees, in Matthew 23:35 (KJV):

And that upon you may come all the righteous blood shed upon the earth, from the blood of righteous Abel unto the blood of Zechariah, son of Barachias, whom ye slew between the temple and the altar.

Where in OT do we find the narrative of Zechariah, son of Barachias, whom Jesus is referring to ? Was he a historical figure not mentioned in OT ? If that be the case, is his case narrated in extra-Biblical writings ?

This question is similar to: Might "son of Barachiah" be a scribal addition in Matthew 23:35?. If you believe it’s different, please [edit] the question, make it clear how it’s different and/or how the answers on that question are not helpful for your problem.

Thanks, Dottard. Against  that question, the OP has not 'accepted'  any answer. My theory in that Zechariah was a prophet of the 400 years silence period, hence not mentioned in OT.

Zechariah 1:1 Zechariah, the son of Berechiah, the son of Iddo the prophet,

Is the question simply a matter of different spelling in the KJV? "Berechiah" in the Hebrew scriptures and "Barachiah" in the Greek scriptures? Other names have similar differences in spelling (e.g. "Noah" vs. "Noe").

As a bit more girst for the mill, I simply copy an explanatory comment made in this study Bible.

"23:35 - Abel to Zechariah.  The murder of Abel is recorded in
Genesis 4:8 and that of Zechariah son of Jehoiada in 2 Chronicles
24:20-22 (Chronicles comes at the close of the OT according to the
Hebrew arrangement.) The expression was somewhat like our 'from
Genesis to Revelation'. Jesus was summing up the history of martyrdom
in the OT." The NIV Study Bible, p.1447, 1987 edition.

In a newer study Bible, it renders verse 35 as this Zechariah being the son of Barachiah, yet its note comes to the same conclusion as that of the NIV.
Then, in Zechariah 1:1, according to this newer version, it reads:

"In November of the second year of King Darius's reign, the Lord gave
this message to the prophet Zechariah son of Berekiah and grandson of
Iddo." NLT Study Bible, p.1527, 2008 edition

Answer: This Zechariah absolutely was a historical figure, not only mentioned in the OT but there is an OT book named "Zechariah". And the astounding accuracy of the dates this book details shows the record was deeply concerned with historical accuracy. Its opening verse gives this Zechariah's father and grandfather's names. Nehemiah informs us that Iddo returned to Jerusalem from exile in Babylon with Zerubbabel and Jeshua (Neh. 12:4). Nehemiah also lists Zechariah as the head of the family of priests descended from Iddo (Neh. 12:1, 16). This suggests that Zechariah was both a priest and prophet in Jerusalem.

The link that Dottard provided includes a lot of helpful information, including the possibility of a scribal error in a MSS:
Might "son of Barachiah" be a scribal addition in Matthew 23:35?
The relevant passages in the Tanakh include
Matthew 23:35 ESV

35 so that on you may come all the righteous blood shed on earth, from
the blood of righteous Abel to the blood of Zechariah the son of
Barachiah, whom you murdered between the sanctuary and the altar.

Zechariah 1:1,2 ESV

1 In the eighth month, in the second year of Darius, the word of the
Lord came to the prophet Zechariah, the son of Berechiah, son of Iddo,
saying, 2 “The Lord was very angry with your fathers.

Zechariah 1:7 ESV

On the twenty-fourth day of the eleventh month, which is the month of
Shebat, in the second year of Darius, the word of the Lord came to the
prophet Zechariah, the son of Berechiah, son of Iddo, saying,

1 Chronicles 27:21

. . . for the half-tribe of Manasseh in Gilead, Iddo the son of
Zechariah; for Benjamin, Jaasiel the son of Abner;

Is Iddo the son of Zechariah or Zechariah the son of Iddo?
2 Chronicles 24:20-22 ESV

20 Then the Spirit of God clothed Zechariah the son of Jehoiada the
priest, and he stood above the people, and said to them, “Thus says
God, ‘Why do you break the commandments of the Lord, so that you
cannot prosper? Because you have forsaken the Lord, he has forsaken
you.’” 21 But they conspired against him, and by command of the king
they stoned him with stones in the court of the house of the Lord. 22
Thus Joash the king did not remember the kindness that Jehoiada,
Zechariah's father, had shown him, but killed his son. And when he was
dying, he said, “May the Lord see and avenge!

However, the Talmud also contains references:
Talmud Sanhedrin 96a

When he reached the Sanctuary, he saw the blood of Zechariah the
priest boiling.

Talmud Sanhedrin 96b

. . . Whereas Zechariah ben Berechiah, the prophet, prophesied during
the Second Temple period and said: “Rejoice greatly, daughter of Zion;
shout, daughter of Jerusalem; behold, your king will come to you; he
is just and victorious; lowly and riding upon a donkey and upon a
colt, the foal of a donkey.” (Zechariah 9:9) . . .

Besides a scribal error, another possibility is a reference to a previous ancestor in that line for symbolic purposes. This is not so outrageous when you think of Jesus indisputably being the son of Joseph, but he's also referred to as the son of David twelve times in the New Testament!
Which of these possibilities is correct has been studied and debated, but there needs to additional MSS evidence before any reliable conclusions can be made.

To make it simple, the answer is 2 Chronicles 24, but someone -- either Matthew, Jesus or a later writer, has confused the son of Berechiah with the son of Jehoiada.

20 Then the Spirit of God clothed Zechariah the son of Jehoiada... 21 But they conspired against him, and by command of the king
they stoned him with stones in the court of the house of the Lord.

Concerning the son of Berechiah, the OT reports very little of his life. In the prolog of Book of Zechariah he is called "son of Berechiah" but in the Book of Ezra (5:1) he is called "son of Iddo," who may have been his grandfather. We can rule this Zechariah out of Matthew's description of a violent death in the Temple, because he prophesied during the Babylonian Exile when the Temple did not exist. Jesus refers to a famous incident, which could only be the one involving the son of Jehoiada.
There is an extra-biblical tradition that the son of Berechiah returned to Jerusalem in his old age, but not that he died violently.  The apocryphal Lives of the Prophets (first c. c.e.) contains an account of his life and death. According to the New World Encyclopedia:

He returned to Jerusalem from Babylonia as an old man and became a
very active prophet in the holy city... He died at
a great age and was buried near Haggai.


There were three major Zechariahs. The son of Jehoiada lived in the time of King Joash of Judah (2 Chron. 24). The son of Berechiah was the author of the Book of Zechariah and  lived in the later part of the Babylonian exile. In the NT there is yet another Zechariah, the father of John the baptist, whose own father is not named. The aprocryphal Infancy Gospel of James mistakenly calls him "high priest" and reports that it was he who was killed in the vestibule of the temple (vs. 23) by Herod I. [NB.. this comment was written in response to a another comment that was later deleted.]
